# Kinect roslaunch error messages

Tags: calibration, kinect, rviz, openni, camera-calibration

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There have been several posts about this, but none seem to be fully resolved.

(I am using ROS fuerte on Ubuntu 12.04)
I tried to install the openNI drivers (using sudo apt-get, rosdep install, and other things I found on different ROS answers pages), but I keep getting the same error when I try to do "roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch".

I get this error message:

```
[ERROR] [1342630897.153525834]: Tried to advertise a service that is already advertised in this node [/camera/depth_registered/image_rect_raw/compressed/set_parameters]
```

I also get a warning that it can't find my camera calibration file but that seems to not be much of an issue.

I tried (among other things), the first answer on http://answers.ros.org/question/33165/visualizing-kinect-output-without-a-turtlebot/ with three terminals and loading rviz. Rviz loads, but with an error message in the Displays menu:

```
Fixed Frame
Fixed Frame [/map] does not exist
```

And I just get a black display instead of a "point cloud".

Anyone have any ideas? (by the way, I'm very new to ROS, if you couldn't tell)

There was also something about openni_node, (when I tried to install that it told me it couldn't find it), but I think that was for the older version.

*********************Update***********
Now I see that after I run rviz, I get this error message, and I think this is why I get no data from the kinect:

```
[camera_nodelet_manager-1] process has died [pid 10040, exit code -6, cmd /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/nodelet_core/nodelet/bin/nodelet manager __name:=camera_nodelet_manager __log:=/home/ben/.ros/log/01490200-d113-11e1-a463-0016cb9a020f/camera_nodelet_manager-1.log].
```

log file: /home/ben/.ros/log/01490200-d113-11e1-a463-0016cb9a020f/camera_nodelet_manager-1*.log

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39180/kinect-roslaunch-error-messages/) by [bschreck](https://answers.ros.org/users/2878/bschreck/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-07-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bschreck](https://answers.ros.org/users/2878/bschreck/) on 2012-07-18**:
@jarvisschultz    So I see what you mean about the Displays error not being a big deal-- I just fixed that. But the problem still exists that I don't see anything. Now there is a Status:Warning thing under the PointCloud2 I made that says Topic: No messages received. Thanks for the quick response!

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2012-07-18**:
To test that the data is actually being sent from the Kinect, try using `rostopic`  For example, in another terminal, type "rostopic hz /camera/depth/points" If this tells you that point clouds are being published at ~30Hz, then you simply have something wrong with your rviz configuration.

**Comment by [bschreck](https://answers.ros.org/users/2878/bschreck/) on 2012-07-19**:
Thanks everyone- I can get data from the kinect now. However, in rviz, I get a very weird small image that doesn't really correspond to anything in the real world. I know that the camera and depth sensor are working though (running image_vew and disparity_view in another window).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Has there been any further news on this topic? It looks like the kinect still doesn't work reliably on 12.04?

---

Originally posted by [ebeowulf](https://answers.ros.org/users/2856/ebeowulf/) with karma: 100 on 2012-08-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2012-08-10**:
I think that is too bold of a statement, it works with no problems on my 12.04 64 bit with Fuerte

**Comment by [Pitscho](https://answers.ros.org/users/2751/pitscho/) on 2012-08-14**:
Doesn't work for me either.  I also run Ubuntu 12.04 64bit fresh updated.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As far as I know, with the new openni_launch package, the `[ERROR]` that you are reporting is quite common (I get it whenever I run the same command you posted).  It really doesn't seem to affect anything.

The error that you are getting with `rviz` has to do with you not choosing a valid "Fixed Frame" for your display.  In the "Displays" panel, be sure that under ".Global Options" your fixed frame is actually a frame that exists. For example, /camera_depth_optical_frame.  Then you should be able to add a PointCloud2 display, and set the topic correctly (something like /camera/depth/points.)

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2012-07-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Regarding the [ERROR] from openni_launch package complaining about trying to advertise a service that is already advertised, you can get rid of it following the instructions on this answer http://answers.ros.org/question/12244/complaint-from-openni_launch-on-already-advertised/#34002

---

Originally posted by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) with karma: 5625 on 2012-07-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2